# How to enable mod_spdy on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, spdy

It has been [announced by Google](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/06/modspdy-is-now-apache-project.html) that it has donated the `mod_spdy` code to the Apache foundation. There is also a [trunk of `mod_spdy` in the Apache SVN](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/mod_spdy/). However, it looks to be in active development.

It's possible to get SPDY working on Apache 2.2, but it seems 2.4 people are stranded in this limbo state until Apache gets their game together. Is this accurate, or is there another way to get SPDY working on 2.4 in the interim?

Answer (score 2):

Give a look on https://github.com/eousphoros/mod-spdy/issues/2#issuecomment-50207584, to clarify your asking. A mod-spdy from apache 2.2 to apache 2.4 is being adapted here

Comment: Seems too unstable to use in production, but still good to see people are working on it.